# addevent keyboard to external swf not working

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I have looked at other questions and online but still cant figure out where I am going wrong
I am adding 2 events to a externally loaded swf

One works, and one doesnt?!?
the function names are correct so I can see what Im missing

```
my_loadedSwf = loadEvent.currentTarget.content as MovieClip;
my_loadedSwf.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, my_loadedSwf.enterFrameHandler);
my_loadedSwf.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,  my_loadedSwf.myOnPress);
addChild(my_loadedSwf);
```

the enterFrameHandler is working, but onPress isnt?!

Any help would be great

Thanks

EDIT:

I have set `my_Loader.tabEnabled = true;`
has not changed anything though

MORE EDITS
Sorry, set `my_loadedSwf.tabEnabled = true;` and it now works great

EDITS TO THE ABOVE
Actually, it isnt working, I have to press 'tab' to take control of the player

### ANSWER

Arrrgh, sorry for all the edits
I removed the tab index code and added focus to the loaded swf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keyboard events are usually captured/listened to at stage level.  You should add the keyboard listener to the stage, and still target whatever handler you want:

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,  my_loadedSwf.myOnPress);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
//Load Complete Event Handler
private function loadCompleteEventHandler(evt:Event):void
{
    //Remove The Event Listener
    evt.currentTarget.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadCompleteEventHandler);

    //Loaded external swf is a display object, so you can add it to the display list
    addChild(evt.currentTarget.content);

    //To access the loaded external swf's public methods and properties you can cast it as an object
    var myExternalSwf:Object = evt.currentTarget.content as Object;

    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, myExternalSwf.enterFrameHandler);
    addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, myExternalSwf.myOnPress);
}
```